# Use order by in pivot table data in Laravel's Eloquent ORM

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have three tables:

1) tasks;

2) visits;

3) task_visit;

Every visit can have 0 or several tasks. I need to sort tasks by a count of visits. For example, 1st task has 4 visits, 2nd - 10 etc.

In a similar case I had two tables:

1) doctors;

2) visits

I sort doctors by visits.

In StatVisit controller:

```
$tests = \App\Doctor::withCount(['visitsbydoctor' => function ($query) use ($a,$b){
  $query->whereBetween('date', array($a,$b));
}])->orderBy('visitsbydoctor_count', 'desc')->paginate(1000000);
```

In doctor model:

```
public function visitsbydoctor()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Visit::class);
}
```

How to rewrite this code in case of a pivot table? For Task model and StatVisit controller as in doctor case.

Answer (score 1):

Use absolutely the same approach. [`withCount()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models) works for many to many relationships as well:

```
Task::withCount('visits')->latest('visits_count')->get()
```

Comment: It doesn't work( 
In your and my version I have error like: 
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'visits.task_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select `tasks`.*, (select count(*) from `visits` where `tasks`.`id` = `visits`.`task_id` and `date` between 2017-11-01 and 2018-12-02) as `taskvisit_count` from `tasks` order by `taskvisit_count` desc limit 1000000 offset 0)

Comment: @befreeforlife if the relationship name is different from a standard one, use it's name. For example, is the relationship name is `taskvisit`, do this: `Task::withCount('taskvisit')->latest('taskvisit_count')->get()`

Comment: It also doesn't work. If I correct understand, in pivot table we need you use 'belongsToMany' and have link on pivot table like 'withPivot('task_visit', 'visit_id')'. You can see it on my answer below, it's work version

Comment: @befreeforlife it works, I've just tested it with many to many relationship in my app. Type of relationship doesn't matter for `withCount()`, it will still generate `relationshipname_count` dynamic column which you can use with `orderBy` method.

Comment: hm, may be cause of error in another. Thank you for help!

Answer (score 0):

I found next work solution:

```
$tests1 = \App\Task::withCount(['taskvisit' => function ($query) use ($a,$b){
      $query->whereBetween('date', array($a,$b));
    }])->orderBy('taskvisit_count', 'desc')->paginate(1000000);


    public function taskvisit()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Visit::class)->withPivot('task_visit', 'visit_id');
}
```

Comment: You don't need to add `withPivot()` here. `withCount()` will still work as I've shown in my answer.